# My Arduino UNO turns LED ON forever when I connect it to my Laptop

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, avrdude, atmega16u2

[image]

My Arduino UNO Board keeps the LED light turned on forever whenever I connect it to my PC. And, when I try to upload even a sample sketch, it says `avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Could you try replacing the ATmega328P? You'll want to check if it's the board or the microcontroller.

Comment: Okay. My ATmega328p is a microcontroller over my Arduino UNO Board. I am a newbie. So help me in fixing that error.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the board? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: Yep. Did it. Check it now.

Comment: Hmm, the chip under the wordt "UNO" is your microcontroller, the brains of the device (: in some Arduino's, it's a replacable one, but this one is unlikely to be replaceable ;p

Comment: What is the chip right under the crystal, at the side of the USB labeled? And did the Arduino work before or is it a new one?

Comment: Cheap Chinese clone by the looks of things...

Comment: Yes, it was working fine. I even did run some programs efficiently over this piece. But, now since last 2 days, it's been giving me that error for whichever Laptop or PC I connect to.

Comment: And about that Chip, @Paul , I don't quite know what it is. A specification guide did not come with this piece.

Comment: @Abhay, it looks like a CH340G, does it have any markings like that? But when you get an upload error, it's often either the "USB chip" or the "microcontroller". (Or just complete fail) can you check the 5V and 3.3V pins, if they do givethe correct voltages?

Comment: When you connect (and disconnect) the device, are you getting the Windows "found device" sound?  If not, it's possible that your device driver is either corrupted or "confused".  If you don't get the sound, then I can walk you through checking the driver.  If you are getting the sound, make sure that in your IDE, that you select the UNO board, and then select the COM port.  It's possible that through plug and play, your COM number has changed, and you IDE is still trying to use the old one.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect the device, if you hear the Windows "found device" sound, then you need to check your COM port driver, as it's very likely that the COM port number may have changed. On your Desktop or in File Manager, right click "This PC" or "My Computer", and select "Manage" from the submenu.  That will bring up the Computer Management console. On the left, select "Device Manager".  That will bring up your list of devices. In the list look for "Ports (COM & LPT)".

[image: Device Manager - Ports]

If you don't see, "Ports", then click "View" and check "Show hidden devices".  If this is the only Arduino that you've ever used, you should only see one listing. Make note of the COM Port Number the driver is using. *It's possible that the port number may have changed since you first used the device. Plug-n-play will do this if you plug the cable into a different USB port that may be using a different USB controller, etc.*

Then in your Arduino IDE, click "Tools", then expand "Boards" and select "Arduino/Genuino UNO" board, then re-click "Tools", and hover over "Port", and select the port number that is assigned to the Port that you found in Device Manager.

If that doesn't work, then you may have a problem with your driver.  Some of the "cheap chinese board" use a different FTDI chipset, so the plug-n-play windows driver may not work. In that case, the manufacturer should point you to the correct driver. Download their provided driver, then you can update the driver in Device Manager.

Comment: As answered by @Zacwolf , I checked that. It hasn't changed for my Arduino UNO. My Port is "USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM 3)" port. It was the same before too.

Comment: And, I discovered one thing more, that before this problem i.e. before few days, it used to connect to any laptop and run any Arduino program. And now, it doesn't connect to any of the Laptop. And, the LED for the Arduino still is ON continuously.

Comment: @Paul , the Chip which you had asked which is placed right under the crystal, at the side of the USB is labeled as AMS1117.

Comment: I do get the sound of Windows found device @ZacWolf whenever I plug it to the computer.

Comment: Help Anyone? ? ? !

Comment: Help me locate the ICSP header pins for Serial interface. I want to check this board by flashing  it's bootloader.

Comment: The 6 pins on the right in the photo are the ICSP header for the Atmega328P chip. You don't have an ICSP header for the Serial chip because it isn't a genuine Uno, and they have used a cheaper USB-to-serial chip which isn't programmable. Under the circumstances, presuming it was cheap, I would just replace the whole board.